# iOS: @testable not seeing internal class in framework

Tags: swift, testing

This has been baffling me for days because I'm sure I've done it in the past. I have a framework (MyFramework) which contains a view controller:

```
import UIKit
public class PublicVC: UIViewController {
    /* In here we use InternalVC */
}

class InternalVC: UIViewController {}
```

And a MyApp target that uses this framework and refers to `PublicVC`.

In the test for the app, I have added the framework as a dependency so I can access the internal VC in the tests and checked that it's also being embedded just to be sure. Then done this:

```
@testable import MyFramework
@testable import MyApp

let public: PublicVC = // works
let internal: InternalVC = // Fails to compile !!! Unresolved Identifier
```

I'm sure I've access internal classes in frameworks in the past for testing, but for some reason this project won't let me see the class not matter what I try.

Anyone have any ideas what I've missed?